# PMF of a balls and bins question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Suppose $r$ distinguishable balls are placed in m labelled bins at random. Each ball has a probability of $p_k$ of going to the $k^{th}$ bin where $p_1 + ... + p_m = 1$ Let $X_k$ be the number of balls that go into the $k^{th}$ bin.

1) Find the PMF of $X_1$

2) Find the PMF of $X_1 + X_2$

So what I have thought till now is that if there were no constraints there would be $m^{r}$ total number of possibilities. So to calculate $X_1$ we need to calculate the probability that the  $k^{th}$ bin has  0  balls to   $k^{th}$ bin has m balls and sum all that up. But I don't know how to take the different probabilities of the balls into account ($p_k$). Have spent days trying to get a solution. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1) you only need to be concerned about a given ball goint into bin 1 (probability $p_1$) or not going into that bin (probability $1-p_1$, you don't care in which other bin it goes).

So you have essentially the following problem: $r$ times you put an object into bin 1 with probability $p_1$ (or not; with probability $1-p_1$). What's the PMF of the number of objects in bin 1? That problem might be something you have encountered in your study, it's a [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

For 2) the problem is similar, now you only care if an object goes into bin 1 or 2 (probability = ?) or not, the principle is the same.

ADDED: Because of a comment by OP, I'm adding a bit to guide them on the right path.

Look up again the definition of a probability mass function (PMF). It answers the question "What is the probability that the random variable I'm interested in is equal to a certain value?", when the possible "certain values" are countable. In this case, if you distribute $r$ balls into bins, the number of balls in any bin is certainly an integer in the range from $0$ to $r$.

So what you need is not a formula for $X_1$, as your comment provides, but a formula for the PMF of $X_1$. Let's calls it $\text{pmf}_{X_1}$. That function needs to depend on $k$, the possible "certain values" ($0,1,\ldots,r$). It also needs to depend on $r$ and the probability that a balls land in bin 1, which is $p_1$. So it needs to depend on $k$, $r$ and $p_1$:

$$\text{pmf}_{X_1} = \text{pmf}_{X_1} (k,r,p_1) $$

Take a look at the linked wikepidia page, it gives the PMF of the binomial distribution, depending on 3 parameters, just like I did above. Can you map that function given there to the funtction above, using the parameter of your problem?

Comment: so $X_1 = \sum_{r=0}^{m} \binom{m}{r}\cdot  p_1^{r} \cdot (p_1 -1)^{m-r}$ and $X_1 + X_2 = \sum_{r=0}^{m} \binom{m}{r}\cdot  p_1^{r} \cdot (p_1 -1)^{m-r} + \sum_{r=0}^{m} \binom{m}{r}\cdot  p_2^{r} \cdot (p_2 -1 )^{m-r}$  ?

Comment: @IshanUpadhyay Added something to answer addressing your question.